# Magento 1.9.2.1 - New customer welcome e-mail is not sending anymore

Tags: email, magento, cron, magento-1.9

our client noticed that welcome emails sent to users after registration (and forgot password) has stopped sending out.

We are using SMTP Pro extension from ASCHRODER with disabled queue, configured to localhost.

Please avoid answers about editing phtml to add field with crftoken. E-Shop was built on 1.9.1 from the beginning.

User is created on registration. Mail queue database table is empty. SMTP Pro self diagnostic sends out the email. Re-sending order from magento admin also sends the email. Only place where email is not sent is Welcome and forgot password.

Is welcome email turned on in configuration? Yes it is and it was always enabled and worked before.

Is cron job running? Yes I have tested it with modifying cron.php to create/modify file by adding time stamp on new line every time it runs.

There is no exception or error in logs.

I can´t tell for 100% but it might stopped working after doing patches from 6788 up to 8788.

-- EDIT --

Compiltion is and was always disabled.

Comment: Is Compilation disabled?

Comment: Yes and it was always disabled.

Comment: What modules are enabled too?

Comment: Disable Module one by one and check

Comment: Or manually send using observer